# Sending a message to a contact on another Android device

Tags: android

While building my first Android app (a simple game), I came across this (most probably newbie) problem:

- my app needs to send a message to a contact (chosen from contact list) via my own server.
- same app installed on this contact's device, needs to retrieve this message.

The problem I am facing is contact "identification". How can the app identify a contact such that one device sends a message for this "ID", and another device polls for messages intended the same "ID?

Maybe there is some kind of ID associated with a contact having an Android device?

Thanks (and sorry for newbie question :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? How to identify different devices or how to send message to another device? Does you app require some king of login ?

Comment: Not talking about identifying different devices, but communicating from my app to the same app installed on a contact's device. Like a messenger.

Having a login would solve this problem, but I was hoping I can do without it using some kind of built-in contact data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try push notifications service, by using the google cloud messaging.
From the first device you can send an http request containing message to a server that manages the request and sends message to the second device, or to more than one device.

You can find a tutorial here 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/